# digit code / number code?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice

Assuming that you need to put the number the material has on the prompt to know the information of the material.

Would it be called "digit code" or "number code" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Whilst both "digit code" and "number code" would be understood they are not the normal wording to use. Assuming that the code is a number then you could use "**numeric code**".

If the code were a mix of alphabetic characters and decimal digits then you could use "**alphanumeric code**".

It would also be correct to simply say "**code**". (Thanks to @Davo for mentioning this in a comment.)

Comment: This. Or just plain **code**.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the "code in digits" or "digits of the code", like in the following sentence:

1. Please input the **code in digits** printed on your application
2. Please input the **digits of the code** printed on your application